# Can't click on blank part that is next to text on a spinner

Tags: android, spinner, dropdown

I'm filling a spinner with a request in HTTP post. It is doing this when I'm heading to my activity. The problem is that when i select the spinner, all the elements are showing themselves but when I'm trying to click on them I can't unless if i click on the text part. I can't click on the red part but only blue part and when words are small it can't be annoying ( here a screen) https://image.noelshack.com/fichiers/2019/22/3/1559131834-screenshot-6.png

I tried to launch it on my emulator and this is working well but when it's on my personal phone which is a Huawei P8 Lite 2017 I can only select the text part. I'm on a fragment

XML FILE

```
<Spinner
     android:id="@+id/exo"
     android:layout_width="0dp"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_weight="0.5"
     android:inputType="text"
     android:textSize="16sp"
     android:textStyle="bold"
     app:fontFamily="sans-serif-condensed-light"
     android:overlapAnchor="false"
/>
```

Code when I click on a Spinner I don't think it will be useful:

```
spnExo.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
   @Override
   public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
       // On selecting a spinner item
       Hold = spnExo.getSelectedItemPosition();

       // Hold = Hold -1;
       StringHold = Integer.toString(Hold);
       //Toast.makeText(getContext(), tabExo[Hold] + " is selected!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
       playerModel.setHold(StringHold);
       Log.d("IMPORTANT", ">>" + playerModel.getHold());
       putre.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); //show textview
       putre1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); //show textview
       putre2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); //show textview
       putre3.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); //show textview
       putre4.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); //show textview
       Analyse(/*"http://192.168.43.58/member/analyse.php"*/"http://172.16.202.2/member/analyse.php",Hold,pre,pui,tps,bro,bjo,ID);
    }
    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
        Hold =0;
        StringHold = Integer.toString(Hold);
        playerModel.setHold(StringHold);

        putre.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); //show textview
        putre1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); //show textview
        putre2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); //show textview
        putre3.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); //show textview
        putre4.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); //show textview
        //  Analyse("http://192.168.43.58/member/analyse.php",Hold);
    }
});
```

I want when I click on a line, the line is selected.

Comment: I recommend to try with at least two or three different android devices.

Comment: Yeah u are right it worked with an other phone. I think my phone is broken but it's getting annoying because I want to make a demo with my phone.

Answer (score 0):

This is not the case with all android devices. Might be your device is having some issue. Try testing the app on other devices too.